# How to implement suggestions on sap.m.Input using xml model?

Tags: sapui5

Hi I am working on live suggestions when I type in an sap.m.Input the value entered will be used to fetch data from mysql db using a java servlet . The results are returned in the form of xml.

Below is the code for the sap.m.Input in the view ,

```
var suggestItem = new sap.ui.core.Item(this.createId("item"),{
        text:"text()"     
        })
var inputUser = new sap.m.Input(this.createId("idUser"),{
            placeholder: "{i18n>userid}",
            type:"Number",
            showSuggestion:true,
            suggest:[oController.showSuggestion, oController]
        }).addStyleClass("inputPadding").bindAggregation("suggestionItems","/plants/plant_name",suggestItem)
```

This is the function in controller which gets called during suggest event

```
showSuggestion:function(oEvent){
 
  mthis = this
  if(!this.getView().byId("idUser").getModel("sample"))
  {
  var sModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();
  this.getView().byId("idUser").setModel(sModel,"sample")
  }
 
var xml = sampleXml(this.getView().byId("idUser").getValue())
 
  ws_sample(xml,function(msg){
  xmldoc = jQuery.parseXML(msg);
  console.log(xmldoc)
  mthis.getView().byId("idUser").getModel("sample").setData(xmldoc)
 
})
}
```

the xml document from server will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<sample>
    <plants>
        <closed>0</closed>
        <district_id>0</district_id>
        <plant_id>7777</plant_id>
        <plant_name>xyz</plant_name>
    </plants>
    <plants>
        <closed>0</closed>
        <district_id>0</district_id>
        <plant_id>7778</plant_id>
        <plant_name>abc</plant_name>
    </plants>
    <plants>
        <closed>0</closed>
        <district_id>0</district_id>
        <plant_id>7779</plant_id>
        <plant_name>ghi</plant_name>
    </plants>
</sample>
```

I am trying to populate the suggestion items using the plant_name.

FYI I am setting the xml document to the sap.m.Inputs model , not the xml string.

there are no errors while running this code however no suggestion comes when I type.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying paths incorrectly.

`text` property for `Item` should be path to property in model which is relatively resolved to path specified as "/plants" in `bindAggregation` method.

```
var suggestItem = new sap.ui.core.Item(this.createId("item"), {
    text: "{plant_name}"
})
var inputUser = new sap.m.Input(this.createId("idUser"), {
    showSuggestion: true,
    suggest: [oController.showSuggestion, oController]
}).addStyleClass("inputPadding").bindAggregation("suggestionItems", "/plants", suggestItem);
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/haqucim/1/edit?html,js,output) is working demo.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , but I have already tried this. This syntax will work for a JSON model, but like I have mentioned in the question , I am using an XML model.What I require is the exact syntax when using an XML model, I have gone through [documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/b8/a2c24356c443228f7819d45697a2b8/content.htm) , and I changed it according to my understanding of it , but its still not working.

Comment: @Abhishek The demo, which has been added after your comment, shows a working example with an XML model. Please consider to accept this answer (click on the checkmark) to let others know that the issue is resolved.